# Get Doctrine Manager outside of Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

so I have a Symfony application and i have to make some cron job services that will run as deamons.

So i want to use normal php files without the whole framework - one custom class however needs  the Doctrine Entity Manager.

How can I start this custom class with the Manager and the Doctrine structure from Symfony in a non-framework php file?

Answer (score 1):

Is creating a standalone php file mandatory for you?

You can create console commands with symfony
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html

if you create a sf2 console command you can call doctrine this way:

$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();

Comment: Yeah I tried that first but even with ContainerAware i can't get it to work... properly I googled and searched here the problem and many have it and there is no functional solution to it.

Also I wouldn't feel good to load the whole framework for this. Scripts like this should be efficient and not load a bunch of data no one needs.

Comment: You should probably try again.  Symfony commands are extremely useful.  And is it really just the entity manager you need?  Doubtful but if so then the Doctrine 2 manual shows how to bootstrap an entity manager:  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#obtaining-the-entitymanager